# What does this English sentence mean?

Tags: grammar

> as clear and detailed as these memories feel, psychologists have discovered they are surprisingly inaccurate.

Since the clause, "as clear and detailed as these memories feel", modifies "psychologists", the sentence implies that these psychologists are clear that the memories are inaccurate.

But this implication just doesn't hit for me. My guess is that the clause doesn't modify the psychologist but instead serve to contrast how the memories feel and how they actually are.

Comment: What made you think that “as clear and detailed as these memories feel” modifies _psychologists_? It does not. It doesn’t modify anything. It’s a subordinate clause. It **refers** to _they_ in the following main clause, but it does not modify it.

Comment: The conjunction 'but' is used to signal a contrast with information that was already introduced - most likely in the sentence which immediately preceded this one. As Janus indicates, 'as clear and detailed as these memories feel' is a subordinate clause referring to the preceding sentence, and can be entirely ignored. You would then have, 'But ... psychologists have discovered *they* [the memories previously referred to] are surprisingly inaccurate.'

Comment: But deleted. @JanusBahsJacquet, doesn't "as clear" modify the subject, which is the psychologist?

Comment: @doeser To be honest I'm nost sure if it modifies the subject (my understanding of grammar language is slim but I'm working on it.:)) it certainly doesn't apply to the psychologists. It applies to how the memories feel. The psychologists are completely independent of the memories. They just ended up discovering [the memories] are surprisingly innacurate.

Comment: @Doeser It's not a modifier; it modifies nothing. You're thinking of dangling modifiers, which are actual modifiers; this is a clause. Had it been “though seemingly clear and detailed”, that would have been a (dangling) modifier, and would have modified the subject of the main clause (MC). But this subordinate clause (SC) does not modify anything. _They_ in the second SC is an anaphoric pronoun, so it requires some type of antecedent—in this case the memories mentioned in the first SC. The subject of the MC is not a proform and thus cannot have an antecedent.

Comment: For more, I suggest you read the [Wikipedia article on anaphora](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_(linguistics)), which is short, but quite clear (just ignore the bit about generative grammar, that's not relevant here).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, would it still be a SC if I say " the river water is clear. Just as clear, the sea water has fish in it."  Here "as" doesn't look like a conjunction to me.

Comment: No, because “just as clear” is not a clause. There’s no verb. It doesn’t work very well as a modifier either, but at least it’s clear that it’s _supposed_ to be a modifier, albeit a clumsy one.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, how about "as clear as the river water is, the sea water has fish in it".

Comment: That is a clause—it has a verb: “as clear as the river water ***is***”. If you take out the verb, it loses its status as a clause and is interpreted as a modifier: “as clear as the river water, the sea water has fish in it”, which would still be an odd sentence, but only semantically—grammatically, it’s fine. (Note: river water frequently has fish, too.)

Comment: That's complicated!

Answer (score 4):

Reinserting the implied 'that' may help.

> But as clear and detailed as these memories feel, psychologists have
>   discovered **that** they are surprisingly inaccurate.

Then we can reorder the sentence:

> But psychologists have discovered **that**, as clear and detailed as
>   these memories feel, they are surprisingly inaccurate.

NOTE

At first sight the problem appears to be caused by starting the sentence with but. However the analysis above shows that the problem can be resolved even if the 'but' is retained.

Comment: Yes "but" doesn't matter here. The reason for my thinking is that whatever comes before the comma modify the subject.

Answer (score 3):

You are right , your interpretation of the sentence is not correct.
You can simplify the sentence in this way:
These memories feel clear and detailed. But psychologists have discovered these memories are inaccurate.
The first clause is in contrast to the main clause and has restricting force similar to "Even if".

Concessive subclauses have an astonishing and confusing variety. So it is advisable to throw a look at adverbial clauses of concession in a grammar.

Answer (score 0):

It means something like this: "Despite the fact that these memories feel clear and detailed, psychologists have discovered that they (the memories) are surprisingly inaccurate."